# Is there an easy way with NSDateFormatter to get "Today", "Tomorrow","Friday" style dates?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm working on setting up NSDateFormatter to explain the date, and I'd like something short but more intuitive than 15/07/10. I think I've seen some formats that will say simply "Today" or "Tomorrow" or the day of the week for subsequent days of the same week. Is there a simple apple-approved way to get this type of date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're targeting iOS 4 or later, you can call `[yourFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES]`. Otherwise, you'll most likely need a custom subclass. As for days of the week, what jer said.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you set up your locale with the NSDateFormatter appropriately, and then ask for the `weekdaySymbols`. This will return an array with the days of the week in the locale you specify.